# Strange String pool behavior

Tags: java, string

I've got a question of some strange String pool behavior.
I'm using `==` to compare equal Strings to find out whether they're in the pool or not.

```
public class StringPoolTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new StringPoolTest().run();
  }

  String giveLiteralString() {
    return "555";
  }

  void run() {
    String s1 = giveLiteralString() + "";
    System.out.println("555" == "555" + "");
    System.out.println(giveLiteralString() == giveLiteralString() + "");
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
true
false
```

which is a big surprise for me. Could anyone explain this please?
I think something about this is taking place at the compilation time. But why does adding `""` to a String makes any difference at all?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Seems the same to me.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I knew the question is slightly different. But the answer is always like "XXX is a compile-time constant, whereas YYY is't". Maybe I had choose a wrong question, though.

Comment: @johnchen902 I agree, but you have posted the wrong question as the duplicate :-)

Comment: Do you really want to compare references or the strings that are returned?

Comment: @MareInfinitus yeah, why not? It's much faster than comparing using equals. Of course you must be sure all the strings are in the pool (e.g. via `intern()`).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
"555" + ""
```

is a [compile-time constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), whereas

```
giveLiteralString() + ""
```

isn't. Therefore the former compiles into just the string constant "555" and the latter compiles into the actual method invocation and concatenation, resulting in a fresh String instance.

---

Also see [JLS §3.10.5 (String Literals)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and
>   therefore distinct.

Comment: can you please provide citation on fresh string instance incase of method invocation? any JLS links ?

Comment: Also, the code optimizer, that runs before/while compilation, might already combine `"555"+""` to a single string object `"555"`

While `method()+""` will still be `method()+""` after compilation.

Comment: @sanbhat Click on "compile-time constant" in my answer.

Comment: Side question: if you were to add `final` to `giveLiteralString()`, would it change anything?

Comment: @RandyMarsh It wouldn't: see the list of allowed expressions for compile-time constants.

Answer (score 32):

After decompiling this line

```
System.out.println("555" == "555" + "");
```

I got this bytecode

```
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ICONST_1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println(Z)V
    ...
```

which is equivalent to

```
  System.out.println(true);
```

that means expression `"555" == "555" + ""` compiles to boolean `true`.

For `giveLiteralString() == giveLiteralString() + ""` javac built this bytecode

```
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    INVOKESTATIC Test1.giveLiteralString()Ljava/lang/String;
    NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
    DUP
    INVOKESTATIC Test1.giveLiteralString()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/String.valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString()Ljava/lang/String;
    IF_ACMPNE L1
    ...
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (giveLiteralString() == new StringBuilder(giveLiteralString()).append("").toString()) {
...
```

which will always produce false since here we're comparing 2 disctinct objects.

Comment: "which will always produce false" -- Technically, StringBuilder is not *required* to produce a non-interned string.  It's simply that there's no good reason for it to attempt to produce an interned one.

Comment: From StringBuilder.toString API -  A new String object is allocated and initialized to contain the character sequence currently represented by this object. This String is then returned.

Comment: But nothing says it can't be interned.

Comment: @HotLicks If it was interned, there could be no guarentee that it was actually new. If the string pool already contained that string, the old instance would be returned by `intern`.

Comment: @HotLicks I read it as a new String object is returned. That is always new, not an object from pool

Answer (score 4):

In the second case the compiler COULD have recognized that `+ ""` is a no-op of sorts, since `""` is a compile-time value known to be zero length.  But the compiler is still required to check the result from `giveLiteralString` for null (since the null check would occur as a result of the `+` operation in the non-optimized case), so it's simplest to just not attempt the optimization.

As a result, the compiler generates code to perform the concatenation, and a new string is created.

Comment: The compiler must comply with the JLS, which explicitly states that the result of runtime concatenation is a fresh string.

Answer (score 0):

**Compile Time Concatenation**
String computed by constant expression are done at compile time and treated as constants or literals means the value of the string or expression is known or evaluated at compile time hence the compiler can check the same value in string pool and the return the same string object reference.

**Runtime Concatenation**
String expressions whose values are known or can not be evaluated at compile but depends on the input or condition of run-time  then the compiler will not know the value of the string and hence always land up using StringBuilder to append the string and always returns a new string .
I guess this example will clarify it better.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new StringPoolTest().run();
  }
  String giveLiteralString() {
    return "555";
  }

  void run() {
    System.out.println("555" + 9 == "555" + 9);  
    System.out.println("555"+Integer.valueOf(9) == "555" + Integer.valueOf(9)); 
    System.out.println(giveLiteralString() == giveLiteralString());
    // The result of runtime concatenation is a fresh string.
    System.out.println(giveLiteralString() == giveLiteralString() + "");
  }
```